# SWT button has border by default

Tags: java, button, swt, border

I am using Java SWT and have created a custom button, and I have not added any border to it.
Still there's a thin border of white color.

How can I remove this?

[image: Image for your reference]

Comment: Please share the code that you use to create the button. Which OS and which version of SWT are you using? Also note, that SWT, by design, leverages the native widgets of the platform on which it is running. As a consequence, the appearance of widgets can only be customized to the extent that the platform supports.

Comment: On some platforms the button just always has a border because that is what the native button control does. If you really don't want a border you could perhaps look at `Link` or a `Label` with a  mouse down listener to behave like a button.

Comment: A ToolBar with ToolItems might also be possiblilty.